# Render partial once page is loaded Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm looking if theres a way to render a partial once the page is fully loaded.

I have a main view `new.vue.erb`

```
<div>
<%= render partial: "builder.vue" %>
</div>
```

And a partial `builder.vue` with a huge vue code with many data processing.

I want to be able to render the `new` view, so I can show a spinner while `builder.vue` loads.

My approach is making an AJAX request when page is loaded, but It wont work:

**New.html.erb**

```
  <div>
      <div id="builderloaded"></div>
    </div>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#builderloaded').html('<%=j render partial: 'campaigns/builder.vue', locals: { f: f } %>')
    });
```

**Controller**

```
   def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
        @categories = Category.all.where(active: true).order(name: :asc)
        @products = Product.where(tipo: "gift", active: 
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render 'new.vue.erb' }
            format.json
            format.js
        end
      end
```

¿Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Once page loading is finished the server-side stuff is done, so you'd have to do some kind of AJAX request (this is also where you'd show a spinner) to get the contents of another partial.

Comment: Strong no on that one. Rendering occurs on the server before the response is even sent to the browser. HTTP is not duplex communication so the server does not know or care about when the browser has finished parsing the response and when the document is ready.

Comment: Also wrapping the code in your `js.erb` in the `jQuery.ready` callback is bound to fail as its very likely that the DOM already is ready when the code is run. I don't really know Vue that well but I belive it has hotloading functionality all ready for loading single file components so whatever you're doing here is most likely a waste of effort. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html